# Finding time taken by the code

Tags: c, profiling, time.h, memmove

I am trying to find the time taken by memmove function in c using time.h library. However, When i execute the code, I get the value as zero. Any possible solution to find the time taken by the memmove function?

```
void main(){
uint64_t start,end;
uint8_t a,b;
char source[5000];
char dest[5000];
uint64_t j=0;

for(j=0;j<5000;j++){
source[j]=j;
}

start=clock();
memmove(dest,source,5000);
end=clock();
printf("%f",((double)end-start));
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code (like the samples in your C text book).

Comment: You get the value zero because memmoving 5000 bytes is probably faster then the resulution of your clock. Tell us more about your platform.

Comment: Do more work. It doesn’t take long enough to copy 5,000  characters for it to be measurable with `clock()`. Or consider using `clock_gettime()`.

Comment: The code is still not indented.

Comment: I have tried the above code on my host pc which is 64 bit windows operating system with i7 processor having 2.7 GHz clock. Also, I have tried the code on my beaglebone board which has ubuntu operating system and has clock of 1Ghz

Comment: In case, I do more work, I might get the time in finite seconds, but that time wont be solely for time required for memmove ,right? @Jonathan Leffler

Answer (score 1):

As I write in my comment, memmoving 5000 bytes is far too fast to be mesurable with `clock`. If you do your memmove 100000 times, then it will get mesurable.

This code below gives an output of `12` on my computer. But this is platform dependent, the number you get on *your* computer might be quite different.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  uint64_t start, end;
  char source[5000];
  char dest[5000];
  uint64_t j = 0;

  for (j = 0; j < 5000; j++) {
    source[j] = j;
  }

  start = clock();

  for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
  {
    memmove(dest, source, 5000);
  }

  end = clock();
  printf("%lld", (end - start));  // no need to convert to double, (end - start)
                                  // is an uint64_t.
 }
```

Comment: This works with Visual Studio, but doesn't appear to work with gcc (release mode). Probably gcc optimization ignores the loop, because the loop does not affect the program result. Also `clock()` depends on `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` which is `1,000` in windows, in *nix I think is usually `1,000,000`

Comment: you can turn off optimization when compiling

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the time it takes on a beagle bone or another device with a GIPO you can toggle a GPIO before and after your routine. You will have to hook up an oscilloscope or something similar that can sample voltage quickly.

I don't know much about beagle bones but it seems the library [libpruio](https://users.freebasic-portal.de/tjf/Projekte/libpruio/doc/html/_cha_examples.html) allows fast gpio toggling.

Also, what is your exact goal here? Compare speed on different hardware? As someone suggests, you could increase the number of loops so it becomes more easily measurable with time.h.